# Detect actual event subscriber in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm facing a problem in my Angular application and I hope someone here can help me.
I'm building a dynamic form component in Angular (8+), in which the various form controls may or may not have event listeners.
In one of those i'm using the information to change the appearance of the component (i.e., if the component instance happens to have an event listener, the cursor turns from default to pointer).

To do so, I'm using a tecnique I read about online:

```
    get iconRightClickable(): boolean {
      return this.iconRightClick.observers.length > 0 
    }
```

Being "iconRightClick" my EventEmitter.

In my dynamic form I'm forced to have the event listeners set in a way similar to the following:

```
    <component 
      (iconRightClick)="params.iconRightClick"
    </component>
```

In this code "params.iconRightClick" may or be not defined, but the check on the amount of observers turns 1 in the exact same way. Looking at the actual content of the observers, they are exactly the same in both cases (undefined param and defined param).

How could I detect that the event callback is actually null or undefined in order to behave properly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using `null` or `undefined` in output event binding. I would probably grab a reference to the component using a template reference variable and conditionally subscribe in code.